# Boot between different ROMs - OnePlus 2

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, stock-rom, dual-boot, oneplus-two

I have an OnePlus Two and I'm currently running stock OxygenOS. I would like to try a beta CM12.1 build without having to delete my data and to be able to boot between the two until the CM build would be stable or suitable for me to use rather than Oxygen. Is there an app that flashes the other ROM and boots to it ? How do you actually do it ?

Comment: Luckily there is methods using sd cards, though don't know them

Comment: Well i don't know anything about dual-booting using SD Cards but OnePlus 2 doesn't have SD Card support.

Comment: Well, that's gives problems. Saying that, I found this:http://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-2/development/dualboot-dualboot-patcher-oneplus-t3221499

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to boot between ROMs using [DualBoot Patcher](https://snapshots.noobdev.io/).I am running OxygenOS as my daily driver and [CyanogenMod 12.1 by Grarak](http://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-2/orig-development/rom-unofficial-cyanogenmod-12-1-t3185511)

**How to do it**:

- Download and install the latest .apk for  [DualBoot Patcher](https://snapshots.noobdev.io/)
- Open the app and go to **Patch Zip File** and select the cm.zip file you downloaded
- At **Partition configuration** tap **Data slot** and enter a Data Slot ID (it can be a number or a word)
- Tap again to patch the file
- Do the same thing with gapps.zip file and supersu.zip (if you want root access)
- Go to **ROMs** and tap the pink FAB button (the pink button in the right corner)
- It will tell you that the feature is experimental, tap ok and then tap the pink FAB button and select the patched zip files in **THIS ORDER**: 1. **cm.zip**, 2. **gapps.zip**, 3. **supersu.zip**
- Tap the tick in the top right corner
- Let it do it's flashing and then go back to **ROMs** and then you should see the CM build on the ROMs list alongside the stock OS
- Tap on it and it should get a green tick next to the picture
- Reboot the phone and then it should boot into CM

**To get back to the other OS you will need to get to the folder you downloaded "DualBoot Patcher.apk" and install it. Then go to ROMs and select the other ROM and then reboot**.

**To change the OS from Recovery Mode you can get "Dual Boot Patcher Utilities" zip from [here](https://snapshots.noobdev.io/). Select "Utilities" instead of Android. Flash it and it should bring a menu where you can select which ROM to boot to**.

If you have any questions leave a comment :)

Comment: I am unable to select the zip file.  Every time I click the button to add zip, the files app opens the zip instead of selecting it

Comment: That is a problem with the built-in file manager. You should install ES File Explorer and select the .zip with that

Comment: But how do I change the default file manager..  I am not getting option to clear default...  I already have ES File Explorer

Comment: On the list from the left under Internal Storage it showed up ES File Explore. It appears now it doesn't show it anymore, and instead it uses the default file manager. What version of Dual Boot Patcher are you using ? I'm using the latest version as of now (yesterday I updated) and it allows me to select with the built-in file manager